# How to enable NestJS code completion, VS Code

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am new to nestjs. Having experience with Node+Expressjs.

I have created a project using nestjs cli. But when I import it into vscode, code-completion is not working. But the tutorial on YouTube it is working.

Can anyone please help me, how to get code completion for nestjs in vscode.

Comment: it's typescript, not 'nestjs'. And you'll get that by default on any typescript project. I didn't follow what you're trying to achieve here. Show us some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still having problem with this configuration in my case I was able to fix this by including "include" option on the `tsconfig.json` file. Go check the `tsconfig-json` [site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). It actually helped a lot. Quoting it literally:

> #Include -
> include
> Specifies an array of filenames or patterns to include in the program. These filenames are resolved relative to the directory containing the `tsconfig.json` file.

It needs to contain your source code folder however you named it. In my case was `src`. Hope this helps other people too. Good coding every one.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

P.S: I abbreviated my `compilerOptions` so I wouldn't mess up any other configurations you guys might have.

Answer (score -1):

It compiles as similar to Nodejs

- First Add project in vs code
- Then go to terminal
- then set your package.json file
- then npm start or npm run start according to your path set.